# iphone; handling latitude/longitudes decimal values with mapkit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, geolocation

Hi there guys
I need help with handling location co-ordinates with xcode; to be precise, the conversions.
i have CLLocation object, which has lat and long received using the phone's geo location, works fine. But i am having issues handling the conversions.

i am storing the lat and long values in the userdefaults using

```
[defaults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.9lf",location.coordinate.latitude]  forKey:@"lastKnownLat"];
```

but the decimal values of the location is ofcourse not precise, its could be 3.123456789 or 3.12345 - in the later case, the value is converted to 3.123459999 which i presume gives wrong positioning on the map.

How can i avoid this? 
What could be the best way to store lat/long values and show them on the map?
in the mapkit, will it maek a lot of difference between 3.12345 and 3.12345999?

Thanks

Comment: You asked if there was a meaningful difference between 3.12345 and 3.12345999 degrees. At the equator, where degrees are as big as they ever get, one degree is about 362775 feet or 110574 meters. Multiply by .000001 and you get 4.3 inches or 11 centimeters. Both are far, far below the accuracy of any GPS, certainly the iPhone's. (For people hung up on accuracy, yes, over mmany calculations an error at the 6th decimal could eventually slide up to a meaningful distance.)

Comment: ah ok, i was wondering abou that, thanks for the insight matthew, certainly educational :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` has methods specifically for saving floating-point values, and you can use [setDouble:forKey:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-SW35) to preserve as much precision as possible.

Comment: If you're going to use NSUserDefaults this is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Hi justin, i have tried that but i get incompatible type error, am using [defaults setValue:location.coordinate.latitude forKey:@"lastKnownLat"] - do i have to do any conversions??

Comment: It should be `setDouble:forKey:`, not `setValue:forKey:`. The latter is identical to `setObject:forKey:` in this case.

Comment: ah okay, got it - thanks, sorry my bad, to not look through the available options carefully.
and my sub-question, will it make a lot of difference when it comes to coordinates 3.12345 and 3.12345999?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to store the data itself could be through Core Data or sqlite, but to have the most accurate data you want to use **kCLLocationAccuracyBest**. See below (refreshLoc is my CLLocationManager variable).

```
refreshLoc = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
refreshLoc.delegate = self;
refreshLoc.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
refreshLoc.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
[refreshLoc startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: thanks squeezemylime, i already have the accurate location, i just need to store it and retrieve it with as much accuracy as possible.

Comment: then set Accuracy ten meters and use kcldistancefilter = one